# Infinite broadcast while location change

Tags: android

I have make a function in activity

```
if (locationManager != null && pendingIntent != null) {
   locationManager.removeUpdates(pendingIntent);
}
Intent intent = new Intent("com.app.android.tracker.LOCATION_READY");
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
            0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

//Register for broadcast intents
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,120000,0,pendingIntent); }
```

and in broadcast receive I have do

```
public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Logger.debug("LocationReceiver->onRceive");
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        Location loc = (Location)b.get(android.location.LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
        Logger.debug("Loc:"+loc);
        if(loc != null){
            //
        }
    } }
```

and in manifest I have do

```
<receiver android:name=".LocationReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.app.android.tracker.LOCATION_READY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

now my problem is while any location is update It do infinitely broadcast n my emulator is hang.
and some time it gives null location

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop requesting location updates. 
You can do it on your onReceive method for example:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
```